# I can't get sequelize to do a basic sql query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm missing something and I think it's simple but I'm struggling. I've followed a blog to get OAuth2.0 working with Node and Sequelize with Postgres. It works...

Now I'm simply trying to add a basic SQL select but I can't get it to work. Can someone please help me?

models/index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

controller/controller.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const OAuthTokensModel = require('../models').OAuthTokens;
const OAuthClientsModel = require('../models').OAuthClients;
const OAuthUsersModel = require('../models').OAuthUsers;
const db = require('../models').db;

module.exports.change = function () {
    return db.sequelize.query(`
        SELECT * FROM "OAuthUsers"
        `,
        {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }
        )
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};

module.exports.getAccessToken = function (bearerToken) {
    return OAuthTokensModel.findOne(
        {
            where: {
                accessToken: bearerToken
            },...
```

I return the following error:

## Cannot read property 'sequelize' of undefined

As I say, I'm sure this is simple, however I'm a sequelize newbie.

Andy

Comment: Note that the SQL query is just to test and get any direct SQL working before moving on to add 'real' queries.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out. I needed to import sequelize *and* remove the .db from my db import:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const TokensModel = require('../models').Tokens;
const ClientsModel = require('../models').Clients;
const UsersModel = require('../models').Users;
const db = require('../models');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports.change = function () {
    return db.sequelize.query(`
        SELECT * FROM "Users"
        `,
        {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }
        )
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing sequelize into your controller

const sequelize = require('sequelize');

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that however it just gives the same error:
"Cannot read property &#39;sequelize&#39; of undefined"